# Acronis copied KUbuntu

Tags: grub2, partitioning, kubuntu, root, initramfs

When I restore an Acronis True Image 10 copy of a running Kubuntu system and try to boot it it stops at a initramfs prompt and says it can't find the root directory.  What commands do I type to re-activate the Grub loader?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to adjust the UUIDs specified in the new `/etc/fstab` file and/or on the kernel command lines in your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. You'll need to update them to match the UUIDs used on your new filesystems. You can learn these UUIDs with the `blkid` command, as in:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="804E-E1FD" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System" PARTUUID="2c47c282-ee6e-45de-a5ad-e8658ca67de6" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="/boot" UUID="c607bd95-8edf-4eb1-aa93-12db8f0e66a2" TYPE="ext2" PARTLABEL="/boot" PARTUUID="053eca6f-f0d4-41d3-9ee3-9f0155c6183e" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="untitled" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="Unused" PARTUUID="a82773de-b428-4399-8f74-754056fa57cf" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="F0FYTX-mtb3-b8Kw-WZ3I-AhB6-JG3l-yCXWkA" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTLABEL="Linux LVM data (nessus)" PARTUUID="54c663df-15d9-4060-beb1-24098073d56d"
```

This output is just for the first few partitions on my computer; it's incomplete, but it gets the idea across. Note the `UUID=` values. You'll need to copy these UUIDs to the target files, replacing the old ones for the equivalent partitions.